# iterate over all possible combinations of params inside a Python dictionary. Pass them as kwargs into a function on each iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

I have a Python dictionary with a dynamic length of params like:

```
'dynamic_params' : {
    'param_1' : [*range(1,3)],
    'param_2' : [*range(1,9)],
    ...
    'param_X' : [*range(1,6)],
},
```

I need to:

a) iterate over all possible combinations. Like:

```
('param_1', 1), ('param_2', 1), ..., ('param_X', 1), 
('param_1', 1), ('param_2', 1), ..., ('param_X', 2),
... 
('param_1', 2), ('param_2', 8), ..., ('param_X', 5),
```

I used ‘***itertools.product***’ without issues for a fixed amount of params. But I couldn't make it work in this case.

b) On each iteration, pass each param combination to a function as kwargs. Like:

```
my_function(
    other_non_related_params,
    param_1 = 1,
    param_2 = 1,
    ...
    param_X = 1,
)
my_function(
    other_non_related_params,
    param_1 = 1,
    param_2 = 1,
    ...
    param_X = 2,
)
...
my_function(
    other_non_related_params,
    param_1 = 2,
    param_2 = 8,
    ...
    param_X = 5,
)
```

How do you recommend to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use argument destructuring to take the cartesian product of many parameters:

```py
from itertools import product

# boilerplate function to print kwargs
def print_kwargs(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

dynamic_params = {
    "param_1": [1, 2],
    "param_2": [1, 2],
    "param_3": [1, 2, 3]
}

param_names = list(dynamic_params.keys())
# zip with parameter names in order to get original property
param_values = (zip(param_names, x) for x in product(*dynamic_params.values()))

for paramset in param_values:
    # use the dict from iterator of tuples constructor
    kwargs = dict(paramset)
    print_kwargs(**kwargs)
```

Output:

```
{'param_1': 1, 'param_2': 1, 'param_3': 1}
{'param_1': 1, 'param_2': 1, 'param_3': 2}
{'param_1': 1, 'param_2': 1, 'param_3': 3}
{'param_1': 1, 'param_2': 2, 'param_3': 1}
{'param_1': 1, 'param_2': 2, 'param_3': 2}
{'param_1': 1, 'param_2': 2, 'param_3': 3}
{'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 1, 'param_3': 1}
{'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 1, 'param_3': 2}
{'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 1, 'param_3': 3}
{'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 2, 'param_3': 1}
{'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 2, 'param_3': 2}
{'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 2, 'param_3': 3}
```